# Should you update custom setting as user in managed package

Tags: managed-package, package, custom

I am trying to update a custom setting in a managed package. If I try to update it "as user" it throws an error, cant see the error as it is in the installed org.
If I update in system mode it is perfectly fine.
I gave all the permissions list custom settings activated, set Custom Setting Definitions, Customize Application, but the error still occurs

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, if you need to update a custom setting in managed package, you should do it with an user that has access to that update operation. If the user does not have the permission explicitly and the operation is still necessary, the update needs to be done through Apex, which ignores the permissions by default.

If it is your package, hide the update behind a Visualforce page or Lightning Web Component. If it is not your package, and you have no control over how it works, then check its documentation/package provider support pages for how your users should be able to perform this operation.